# Create list of tuples from 2d array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm looking to create a list of tuples from a 2xn array where the first row is an ID and the second row is that IDs group assignment. I'd like to create a list of the IDs organized to their group assignments.

For example:

```
array([[ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  1.,  2.,  2.,  1.,  1.])
```

In the above example, ID 0 is assigned to group 1, ID 1 to group 2 and so on. The output list would look like:

```
a=[(0,2,5,6),(1,3,4)]
```

Does anyone have any creative, quick ways to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard (sorry, not creative -- but reasonably quick) numpy way would be an indirect sort:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array([[ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.],
                 [ 1.,  2.,  1.,  2.,  2.,  1.,  1.]])

index = np.argsort(data[1], kind='mergesort') # mergesort is a bit
                                              # slower than the default
                                              # algorithm but is stable,
                                              # i.e. if there's a tie
                                              # it will preserve order
# use the index to sort both parts of data
sorted = data[:, index]
# the group labels are now in blocks, we can detect the boundaries by
# shifting by one and looking for mismatch
split_points = np.where(sorted[1, 1:] != sorted[1, :-1])[0] + 1

# could convert to int dtype here if desired
result = map(tuple, np.split(sorted[0], split_points))
# That's Python 2. In Python 3 you'd have to explicitly convert to list:
# result = list(result)
print(result)
```

Prints:

```
[(0.0, 2.0, 5.0, 6.0), (1.0, 3.0, 4.0)]
```